# Excel calculation to be reflected in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has two columns that could potentially be updated with user input. The first is a percentage, and the second is a dollar value.

If a user edits the first column and enters a percentage, I would like the second column to update with the appropriate dollar value. However, if they go and change the dollar value, I would like the percentage column to be updated.

I have this working by simply using a calculation in the cell; however if the values are changed, the formula is clobbered with the value that is entered.

I would like the user to be able to enter a dollar value, have the percentage updated, and then have the ability to modify the percentage and have the dollar value updated.

Is this possible?

Any help and guidance at all will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What do the dollars and percentages correspond to?  You can probably use code in the `Worksheet_Change` event that could handle input in both columns, but without sample data I'm not sure I can do much more.

Comment: I assume that you have a formula which will calculate the dollar/percentage once the other value is known?  If so, you could use the `Worksheet_Change` event to replace the other cell with the correct formula like @JoshuaRoss recommends.  I personally would handle this with only formulas which can be done easily by adding two columns.  That gives two columns for input (of which only 1 is used) and 2 for output which are calculated based on the input provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you, you will need to change to the appropriate range, as well change the formulas,

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Range("A2:B100")
    If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range(Target.address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Column = 1 Then ' Value in first column changed
            Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = 2 * Range("A" & Target.Row).Value
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Target.Column = 2 Then ' value in second column changed
            Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = 1 / 2 * Range("B" & Target.Row).Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you. Just to note for any future readers that I threw myself into an infinite loop.

'Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.EnableEvents = True'

Were needed to be set at the start and end of the code respectively.

Comment: You are welcome, Please accept the reply as answer if you are satisfied with it